# REACT JS POST http://localhost:4000/api/activation 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-router, react-hooks, mern

Hi I was working on **Activating** an email account using **JWT** now how it was working is after a User is registered a User receives an email through a link that they are supposed to click and they will be navigated to the **Activate.js Page** where they will find a button which they are supposed to click and activate their account.

This is where my error comes in when I click the Activate button I get an error as displayed below and here is a Chrome image(below) to the error as displayed in the Chrome console. [image]

> POST http://localhost:4000/api/activation 401 (Unauthorized)

The suspicions to my problem I think could be the **POST ROUTE** for my **Activate.js file** this is the code below for the POST Route specifically.

```
  //   const { name, show, token } = formData;
  const { username, show } = formData;

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios
      .post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/activation`, {
        token
      })
      .then(res => {
        setFormData({
          ...formData,
          show: false
        });
        toast.success(res.data.message);
      })
      .catch(err => {      
        toast.error(err.response.data.errors);
      });
  };

  const navigate = useNavigate();
```

And the code below is the full code for my **Activate.js file** together with my **POST Routes** all combined.

**Activate.js Code**

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import authSvg from '../assets/welcome.svg';
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import axios from 'axios';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { authenticate, isAuth } from '../helpers/auth';
// import { Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Link as RouterLink, useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const Activate = ({ match }) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    username: '',
    token: '',
    show: true
  });

  const { token } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    /*   get token from params like /active/token
    then decode this token and get name*/
    // let token = match.params.token;
    let username = jwt.decode(token);

    if (token) {
      setFormData({ ...formData, username, token });
    }

    console.log(token, username);
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
//   const { name, show, token } = formData;
  const { username, show } = formData;

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios
      .post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/activation`, {
        token
      })
      .then(res => {
        setFormData({
          ...formData,
          show: false
        });
        toast.success(res.data.message);
      })
      .catch(err => {      
        toast.error(err.response.data.errors);
      });
  };

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <div className='min-h-screen bg-gray-100 text-gray-900 flex justify-center'>
      {isAuth() ? <navigate to='/app/dashboard' /> : null}
      <ToastContainer />
      <div className='max-w-screen-xl m-0 sm:m-20 bg-white shadow sm:rounded-lg flex justify-center flex-1'>
        <div className='lg:w-1/2 xl:w-5/12 p-6 sm:p-12'>
          <div className='mt-12 flex flex-col items-center'>
            <h1 className='text-2xl xl:text-3xl font-extrabold'>
              Welcome
              {/* Welcome {name} */}
            </h1>

            <form
              className='w-full flex-1 mt-8 text-indigo-500'
              onSubmit={handleSubmit}
            >
              <div className='mx-auto max-w-xs relative '>
                <button
                  type='submit'
                  className='mt-5 tracking-wide font-semibold bg-indigo-500 text-gray-100 w-full py-4 rounded-lg hover:bg-indigo-700 transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out flex items-center justify-center focus:shadow-outline focus:outline-none'
                >
                  <i className='fas fa-user-plus fa 1x w-6  -ml-2' />
                  <span className='ml-3'>Activate your Account</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className='my-12 border-b text-center'>
                <div className='leading-none px-2 inline-block text-sm text-gray-600 tracking-wide font-medium bg-white transform translate-y-1/2'>
                  Or sign up again
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className='flex flex-col items-center'>
                <a
                  className='w-full max-w-xs font-bold shadow-sm rounded-lg py-3
           bg-indigo-100 text-gray-800 flex items-center justify-center transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out focus:outline-none hover:shadow focus:shadow-sm focus:shadow-outline mt-5'
                  href='/register'
                  target='_self'
                >
                  <i className='fas fa-sign-in-alt fa 1x w-6  -ml-2 text-indigo-500' />
                  <span className='ml-4'>Sign Up</span>
                </a>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='flex-1 bg-indigo-100 text-center hidden lg:flex'>
          <div
            className='m-12 xl:m-16 w-full bg-contain bg-center bg-no-repeat'
            style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${authSvg})` }}
          ></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      ;
    </div>
  );
};

export default Activate;
```

For some reason I also think the error could be that I need to have added headers but  I tried implementing headers as below

```
headers: {  
  Accept: 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
},
```

But their was no luck to the above code and decided to inquire from this platform.

Also for my other suspicions I kind of think the error could be the way I was routing the **isAuth()** in the **Activate.js**  for example I am using **"react-router": "^6.0.0-beta.0",** with a code I was following later on they were using **Redirect** and in my version Redirect is no longer supported so I tried using **useNavigate** as navigate.

Below are the code samples.

Here is the **Redirect** code I was trying to refer to from the tutorial

```
{isAuth() ? <Redirect to='/app/dashboard' /> : null}
```

And Here is how I modified it using **navigate** instead of **Redirect** `{isAuth() ? <navigate to='/app/dashboard' /> : null}` because am suspecting maybe it wants to post and route the code and it fails due to the way I had modified the **Redirect** in order to use **navigate** this is just my other theory of it bringing this error.

Another **suspicion** of this **error** I was suspecting and thing could also be the way I had configured my **bodyParser** in my **backend** since this is a **MERN App** am working on and this is the sample code of how I had configured my **bodyParser** in my **index.js** file in the **backend side**.

```
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

The Code below is illustration for my **Activation routes.js File**;

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
const express = require('express');
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const router = express.Router();

// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
// const RegistersignUp = require('../model/registerSignUpmodel');

// Load Controllers
// import controller (new method)
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
const {
  registersignUp,
  activationController, // Here is where I export my activationController from controllers.
  loginController,
  forgetController,
  resetController,
  // activateAccount,
} = require('../controllers/registerauth');

// Validation
const {
  validRegister,
  validLogin,
  forgotPasswordValidator,
  resetPasswordValidator,
} = require('../helpers/valid');

router.post('/register', validRegister, registersignUp);
// router.post('/login', loginController);
router.post('/login', validLogin, loginController);
router.post('/activation', activationController); //On this line is how  I route my activation
router.put('/password/forget', forgotPasswordValidator, forgetController);
router.put('/password/reset', resetPasswordValidator, resetController);

module.exports = router;
```

Lastly my **/controllers/registerauth** whereby in my **registerauth.js** is where I store **controllers** for my **User Registeration**.

In the code below I have only specified the **activationController** because its the one we are working on to solve the error.

```
/* eslint-disable no-param-reassign */
/* eslint-disable no-lonely-if */
/* eslint-disable no-dupe-keys */
/* eslint-disable no-shadow */
/* eslint-disable no-else-return */
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
/* eslint-disable arrow-body-style */
/* eslint-disable object-shorthand */
/* eslint-disable no-sequences */
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
const expressJwt = require('express-jwt');
const _ = require('lodash');
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-unresolved
const { OAuth2Client, UserRefreshClient } = require('google-auth-library');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const { validationResult } = require('express-validator');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
// I will use for send email sendgrid you can use nodemailer also
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
const mailgun = require('mailgun-js');
const mail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
const RegistersignUp = require('../model/registerSignUpmodel');
// Custom error handler to get useful error from database errors
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-unresolved
const { errorHandler } = require('../helpers/dbErrorHandling');

const DOMAIN = 'sandboxb7287b4c62c74643864ccb6d8de5f0c6.mailgun.org';

// eslint-disable-next-line no-use-before-define
const mg = mailgun({ apiKey: process.env.MAILGUN_APIKEY, domain: DOMAIN });

// sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.MAIL_KEY);

exports.activationController = (req,res) => {
  const { token } = req.body

  if (token) {
    // Verify the token is valid or not or expired
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION,
      (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(401).json({
          error: 'Expired Token, Signup again'
        })
      } else {
        // if valid save to database
        // Get username phone email firstName lastName password
        const { username, email, phone, firstName, lastName, password } = jwt.decode(token)
    
        const user = new RegistersignUp(     {
          username,
          email,
          phone,
          firstName,
          lastName,
          password,
        })
    
        user.save((err, user) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log('Save error', errorHandler(err));
            return res.status(401).json({
              errors: errorHandler(err)
            });
          } else {
            return res.json({
              success: true,
              message: 'Signup success',
              user,    
            });
          }
        })
      }
    })
  } else {
    return res.json({
      message: 'error happening please try again'
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: the 401 status code comes from the backend so the issue is probably in the backend. share you controller code for this route

Comment: I have successfully added the controller code for this route as requested, Thank You for getting back.

Comment: So what do the backend logs say? You have multiple error messages possibly logged

Comment: I just noticed my mistake earlier on my token had expired hence it causing the **"401 Unauthrized Error"** I resubmitted a fresh token and it worked successfully as in the image link below. https://imgur.com/FizSnVA  If you notice on your right hand side you can view a successful react toast message of "Signup Success" I actually struggled troubleshooting all this yet this was the only problem am really so sorry but I reciprocate and appreciate you getting back to my question, Thank You Very Much. I don't know if their is anything I can do to upgrade the code or leave it as it is.